# Loss does not decrease

Tags: pytorch, neural-network, loss-function

I'm a beginner and just trying to get in pytorch and neural networks. Therefore I created some dataset. The dataset consists of two input variables and one output variable (basicly the output is a linear function with some noise). Now I want to set up a neural network and train it with the dataset. I followed some tutorial and wrote this code:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r" ... .csv")

X = df[["x", "y"]]
y = df[["goal"]]

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=.2, random_state=42)
X_train, y_train = np.array(X_train), np.array(y_train)
X_test, y_test = np.array(X_test), np.array(y_test)

# Convert data to torch tensors
class Data(Dataset):
       def __init__(self, X, y):
              self.X = torch.from_numpy(X.astype(np.float32))
              self.y = torch.from_numpy(y.astype(np.float32))
              self.len = self.X.shape[0]

       def __getitem__(self, index):
              return self.X[index], self.y[index]

       def __len__(self):
              return self.len

batch_size = 32

# Instantiate training and test data
train_data = Data(X_train, y_train)
train_dataloader = DataLoader(dataset=train_data, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)

test_data = Data(X_test, y_test)
test_dataloader = DataLoader(dataset=test_data, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)

input_dim = 2
hidden_dim_1 = 2
output_dim = 1

class NeuralNetwork(nn.Module):
       def __init__(self, input_dim, hidden_dim_1, output_dim):
              super(NeuralNetwork, self).__init__()
              self.layer_1 = nn.Linear(input_dim, hidden_dim_1)
              self.layer_out = nn.Linear(hidden_dim_1, output_dim)

       def forward(self, x):
              x = F.relu(self.layer_1(x))
              x = self.layer_out(x)
              return x

model = NeuralNetwork(input_dim, hidden_dim_1, output_dim)

optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.01)

def train(epoch):
       model.train()
       for batch_id, (data, target) in enumerate(train_data):
              data = Variable(data)
              target = Variable(target)
              target = target.to(dtype=torch.float32)
              optimizer.zero_grad()
              out = model(data)
              criterion = F.mse_loss
              loss = criterion(out, target)
              print(loss.detach().numpy())
              loss.backward()
              optimizer.step()

for epoch in range(1, 30):
       train(epoch)
```

Here the code I used to create a test dataset:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

list_x = []
list_y = []
list_goal = []

for i in range(0, 10000):

    list_x.append(i)
    list_y.append(int(np.random.rand()*10))
    list_goal.append(3*i + list_y[i] + np.random.rand()*2)

df_new = pd.DataFrame()

df_new['x'] = list_x
df_new['y'] = list_y
df_new['goal'] = list_goal

df_new.to_csv(r"..." + '.csv',sep=',', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

My problem is that the printed loss is extremly high (e8-area) and does not decrease.

I tried to change some settings of the neural network, changed the batchsize, learningrate and tried other optimizers and loss functions. But none of the changes really helped. My research also didn't bring any success. Seems to me that there is a more basic mistake in my coding. What did I wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems like you redefine the loss function in every training loop. That might cause problems. I normally do `criterion = torch.nn.MSELoss()` once before starting the training loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine to me (although I might miss a bug). It is in general never safe to say which networks will be successful and which won't, but here are some suggestions if you can't see any progress:

- **Check the input data.** Maybe try plotting it to make sure that it actually contains what you think it does. You may print out the inputs, predicted and expected values (or better, view them in a debugger) to see what's wrong.
- **Normalize the input data.** If there are high values in the input / output data, losses may explode. Ensure that most of the values are roughly between -1 and 1.

*Edit: That seems to be the main problem here. It worked when I changed the data generation loop to the following:*

```
n_iterations = 10000
for i in range(0, n_iterations):
    list_x.append(i / n_iterations)  # divide by 10k
    list_y.append(int(np.random.rand() * 10))
    list_goal.append((3 * i + list_y[i] + np.random.rand() * 2) / n_iterations)  # divide by 10k
```

*You were previously generating values above 10k, which is to high for that network.*

- **Lower the learning rate.** 0.01 is generally a good starting point, but who knows.
- **Try training for more epochs.** Depending on the noise in your data, this could be necessary.
- **Try adding more neurons.** A linear function should in theory be fine with not that many, but maybe the noise is too 'complex'.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I made some changes und tested some configurations due to your proposals but unfortunately I wasn't able to solve the problem yet... :/

Comment: @doctor Then you could try to find a demo code (e.g. from the tutorial) that works on your machine and change it line by line (and run after each change) until it looks like yours. Maybe that can help you spot the issue? You could also post a link to the original csv file (e.g. using https://pastebin.com/) so I can check it on my computer.

Comment: I added the code I used to create the test dataset above. Maybe this helps to find the problem...

Comment: @doctor I just got it running when decreasing the input values. See the edit :)

Comment: Perfect! Do you have a hint for me how to face this problem with more complex datasets? I also tried to use MinMaxScaler() before but that did not work. Is there a general way how to normalize datasets best?

Comment: @doctor I have not tried MinMaxScaler yet. I often just prepared the dataset once with a simple loop, but it depends on the initial format. I just found that article on the web, maybe it can help you: https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/big-data-&-business-intelligence/9781788474221/2/ch02lvl1sec26/normalizing-the-input-data-for-the-neural-network